# what is the time complexity of this code where it may go infinte loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, infinite-loop

I'm trying to find the time complexity of this code.

```
 while(m!=4){
        if(m>n)
               m=m-n
        else
               n=n-m
    }
```

I've tried random values for m & n which makes it an infinite loop. I don't know how to find it?

Comment: If the code doesn't solve the problem, then there is no sense to time complexity, because time complexity suggests the time taken to receive an answer.

Comment: Code that doesn't terminate doesn't have a time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

This time complexity only makes sense if the algorithm terminates. A necessary condition is `gcd(m, n) | 4`. But it is not sufficient.

Now it is easy to see that the worst case (slowest decrease) occurs when `m = 1` or `n = 1`, so that the complexity is `O(max(m, n))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will get into an infinite loop for almost every m and n, as for most m and n one of them will reach 0, and it will become an infinite loop (n = n - 0). Also, m has to be larger than 4, or the loop will keep going until m or n reaches 0, again, the same case. The only way that your loop gets terminated is when m - n*k = 4, with k being an integer. Or, when m is bigger than n, m - (n-m*k) = 4. Time complexity, in this case, will be O( |m-n| ), linear in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

It's amusing the amount of times almost every test case would end up triggering the loop into a perpetual state.
MAYBE the code that you MIGHT be looking for COULD BE:
the gcd(m,n) just a very tiny but pivotal tweak:

```
while(m!=n)
{
    if (m>n)
        m=m-n;
    else 
        n=n-m;
}
```

In this case, the time complexity is going to be in order of n.